# ObjectMapper toJson empty

Tags: ios, json, swift3, objectmapper

I'm trying to deserialize an object into a JSON dictionary with [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) but the deserializing functions always return empty objects.

```
class TimeEntryContainer: Mappable {

//MARK: Properties
var entry: TimeEntryObject = TimeEntryObject()

//MARK: Initializers
init() {}

init(_ issue: Issue, hours: Double, activityId: Int) {
    self.entry = TimeEntryObject(issue, hours: hours, activityId: activityId)
}

required init?(map: Map) {
    mapping(map: map)
}

//MARK: Private Methods
func mapping(map: Map) {
    entry       <- map["time_entry"]
}    
}

class TimeEntryObject {

//MARK: Properties
var issueId = -1
var projectId = ""
var hours = Double()
var activityId = -1
var comments = ""

//MARK: Initializers
init() {}

init(_ issue: Issue, hours: Double, activityId: Int) {
    self.issueId = issue.id
    self.projectId = issue.project
    self.hours = hours
    self.activityId = activityId
}

required init?(map: Map) {
    mapping(map: map)
}

//MARK: Private functions
func mapping(map: Map) {
    issueId         <- map["issue_id"]
    projectId       <- map["project_id"]
    hours           <- map["hours"]
    activityId      <- map["activity_id"]
    comments        <- map["comments"]
}
}
```

Here's the part where I fill my TimeEntryContainer object

```
let timeEntry = TimeEntryContainer()
timeEntry.entry.projectId = (issue?.project)!
timeEntry.entry.activityId = activityId
timeEntry.entry.hours = timeEntered
timeEntry.entry.comments = commentEdit.text ?? ""

let deserialized = Mapper().toJSONString(timeEntry)
print("hours: \(deserialized) ")
```

Even though the values of my `timeEntry` object are correctly set, the functions `Mapper().toJSONString()`, `Mapper().toJSON()` and even `timeEntry.toJSON()`  and `timeEntry.toJSONString()` return an empty JSON object / dictionary. I can't find where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TimeEntryObject must be Mappable.  You put in the methods but you didn't declare conformance in the class declaration.

```
class TimeEntryObject: Mappable
```

Comment: ... The bigger it is, the less you see it. Thanks.

Comment: I also have this problem, tried both with mappable struct and class. `toJSON` and `toJSONString` result is empty. Swift 3, Xcode 8. ObjectMapper 2.2.7

Comment: The problem was in how I initialise the object, if I initialise it with designated init for every property, it works. Empty init() method and assigning variables didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, in my case I have Mappable protocol implemented. Biut I had not mapped the variables of class which was giving me empty json.

Posting as just another option/ solution. May help someone in case required.